# Combinatorics of the sum of two dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In my probability book I learned how to solve this kind of problem: how many vectors of the form $(i_1,i_2,...,i_r)$ exist that the sum of its components is $n$ and $i_k>0$ for all $k$? The answer uses the stars and bars argument and is $n-1\choose r-1$.

OK, now I have this really simple problem: imagine you'll roll $2$ six-faced dice, how many ways there are in which the sum of them is $n$?

First I thought to use the before mentioned method, considering a result as a vector of the form $(i_1,i_2)$ but I realized that I have a new restriction, $i_1,i_2 \leq 6$! I thought about it and I don't know how to compute it without considering case by case ($n=2,n=3,...,n=12$), I've done it with the six-faced die, since there's only $11$ cases and found a nice 'triangular pattern', but what if the dice had each $20$ faces? Is there a more smart way to calculate it?

Comment: The plural of die is dice.  Alas, it does not conform to the usual rules for forming the plural.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**:

This might help. 
$$\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
  & \color{red}1 & \color{red}2 & \color{red}3 & \color{red}4  & \color{red}5  & \color{red}6  \\ \hline
\color{red}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  & 6  & 7  \\ \hline
\color{red}2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  & 7  & 8  \\ \hline
\color{red}3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7  & 8  & 9  \\ \hline
\color{red}4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  & 9  & 10 \\ \hline
\color{red}5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9  & 10 & 11 \\ \hline
\color{red}6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

---

Let $n$ be your sum, then notice that

- if $n\leq 6$, then there are $n-1$ ways to make a sum equal to $n$.
- if $n\geq 7$, then there are $13-n$ ways to make a sum equal to $n$.

We can jusify this as follows. Say you want to pick two numbers $a,b$ so that $$a+b=n$$ We can only focus on $a$, since for a fixed $a$ we know that $b=n-a$. The smallest value for $a$ is $1$, and the largest value for $a$ is therefore $n-1\geq n-a$. Thus there are $n-1$ ways to choose $a$ (and we have no choice for $b$).

We get the other case by symmetry: $12-(n-1)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Six-sided dice problem:**

Suppose we have a red die and a white die.  If we denote the number shown on the red die by $x_r$ and the number shown on the white die by $x_w$, then the sum of the numbers on the two dice satisfies
$$x_r + x_w = n \tag{1}$$
where $x_r$ and $x_w$ are positive integers.  For six-sided dice, we have the additional restriction that $x_r, x_w \leq 6$.  Without that restriction, equation 1 has 
$$\binom{n - 1}{2 - 1} = \binom{n - 1}{1} = n - 1$$
solutions in the positive integers. From these, we must subtract those solutions in which one of the variables exceeds $6$.

If $n \leq 7$, this is impossible, so there are simply $n - 1$ solutions.

Suppose $n > 7$.  Moreover, suppose $x_r \geq 7$.  Then $x_r' = x_r - 6$ is a positive integer.  Substituting $x_r' + 6$ for $x_r$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_r' + 6 + x_w & = n\\
x_r' + x_w & = n - 6 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the positive integers with 
$$\binom{n - 6 - 1}{1} = \binom{n - 7}{1} = n - 7$$
solutions.  By symmetry, equation 1 also has $n - 7$ solutions in the positive integers with $x_w > 6$.

Hence, the number of ways two six-sided dice can have sum $n > 7$ is 
$$n - 1 - 2(n - 7) = n - 1 - 2n + 14 = 13 - n$$
The approach is analogous for $20$-sided dice.

Answer (score 0):

If the first die shows $d$, the other must show $n-d$. You must fulfill the constraints

$$1\le d\le6,\\1\le n-d\le 6$$ or

$$\max(1,n-6)\le d\le\min(6,n-1).$$

The requested number is

$$\min(6,n-1)-\max(1,n-6)+1.$$

---

In a simpler way,

$$2=1+1,
\\3=2+1|1+2,
\\4=3+1|2+2|1+3,
\\5=4+1|3+2|2+3|1+4,
\\\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

(Generating functions method) If $A$ is the first dice roll result and $B$ is the second, you want the number of pairs $(A,B)$ such that $A+B=n$, restricted by $A,B\in \{1,2,3,\dots,6\}$. This is (if dice ordering is important)

$$ S_n=\sum_{k=0}^6 \mathbb 1_{k} \mathbb 1_{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb 1_{k} \mathbb 1_{n-k}, \quad \mathbb 1_k := \begin{cases}1 & k\in  \{1,2,3,\dots,6\}, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
i.e. it is the convolution product of the sequence $\mathbb 1_k$ with itself. Recall that convolution products correspond to the coefficients of the product of polynomials(or even formal power series),

$$ A(x) = \sum a_i x^i , B(x) = \sum b_i x^i \implies A(x)B(x) = \sum c_i x^i, \quad c_i =\sum_{i=0}^na_i b_{n-i}.$$

So lets consider
$P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\mathbb 1_k x^k  = \sum_{k=1}^6 x^k = x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^6 $. Then the product
$$ P(x)^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{12} S_k x^k.  $$
On the other hand,
$$P(x)^2 =  \left( \sum_{k=1}^6 x^k\right)^2 =       x^2 + 2 x^3+ 3 x^4+ 4 x^5 + 5 x^6 + 6 x^7 + 5 x^8+ 4 x^9+ 3 x^{10}+ 2 x^{11}+ x^{12}. $$

So computing this polynomial $P(x)^2$ computes all elements of $S_n$ at once. To get the answer for 20, just change 6 to 20 and compute the polynomial $P(x)^2 = (\sum_{k=1}^{20} x^k)^2$. This is just (I see no one else here has computed this explicitly)
$$P(x)^2 = x ^ { 40 } + 2 x ^ { 39 } + 3 x ^ { 38 } + 4 x ^ { 37 } + 5 x ^ { 36 } + 6 x ^ { 35 } + 7 x ^ { 34 } + 8 x ^ { 34 } + 8 x ^ { 33 } + 10 x ^ { 32 } + 10 x ^ { 31 } +
11 x ^ { 30 } + 12 x ^ { 29 } + 13 x ^ { 28 } + 14 x ^ { 27 } + 15 x ^ { 26 } + 16 x ^ { 25 } + 17 x ^ { 24 } + 18 x ^ { 23 } + 19 x ^ { 22 } +
20 x ^ { 21 } + 19 x ^ { 20 } + 18 x ^ { 19 } + 17 x ^ { 17 } + 16 x ^ { 17 } + 15 x ^ { 16 } + 14 x ^ { 15 } + 13 x ^ { 14 } + 12 x ^ { 13 } +
11 x ^ { 12 } + 10 x ^ { 11 } + 9 x ^ { 10 } + 7 x ^ { 9 } + 6 x ^ { 7 } + 5 x ^ { 6 } + 4 x ^ { 5 } + 3 x ^ { 4 } + 2 x ^ { 3 } + x ^ { 2 }
$$

So for instance, there are 19 ways to get a sum of 22 with 2 20-sided dice. Its easy to generalise this to any number of dice as well: if you want the number of ways to get $k$ from rolling $M$ distinct $N$-sided die, look at the $k$th coefficient in $(\sum_{1}^N x^k)^M$. This method is very robust and can solve many other counting problems, [see e.g. this wikipedia page of examples,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_generating_functions) and also the incredible Generatingfunctionology book linked at the bottom of that page.