# Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \alpha^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, divergent-series, time-series

I'm struggling with the derivation of this **known** result. As a prerequisite, consider the following results. Suppose we have time-series data {$x_i$ for $i = 1, \dots, N$} from a **stationary** process having mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and theoretical acf $\rho(k)$. The sample mean is $\bar{X} = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{X_i}{N}$. For correlated observations, it can be shown that the sample mean variance is not $\sigma^2/N$ but is given by:

$$
Var(\bar{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{N}\left[ 1 + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\left( 1 - \frac{k}{N} \right) \rho(k) \right]
$$

I'd like to find the variance of the sample mean for a stationary AR(1) process. The book states that $Var(\bar{X})$ for AR(1) reduces to $ Var(\bar{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{N}\left( \frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha} \right)$. To show this, I start with the autocorrelation function of an AR(1) process with parameter $\alpha$ which is $\rho(k) = \alpha^{|k|}$ where $\alpha \lt 1$. So the above equation becomes

$$
Var(\bar{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{N}\left[ 1 + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\left( 1 - \frac{k}{N} \right) \alpha^k \right]
$$

Then let $N \rightarrow \infty $. The complication then is ultimately in solving $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1 - \frac{k}{N}) \alpha^{|k|}$. If I split it then:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha^k - 1 = \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}
$$

Now I need to solve the second part which is where I get stuck. **I don't know how to evaluate**:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \alpha^k
$$

Ultimately, I'd like to show that $ Var(\bar{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{N}\left( \frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha} \right)$ but I believe by solving the above sum which I'm stuck on I'll be able to show this result from the general equation for $Var(\bar{X})$ above.

Comment: Isn't $|k|$ just $k$?

Comment: @KentaS Yes, because of the limits. I've kept the abs but effectively it is just k.

Comment: Then you should be able to evaluate it by taking the derivative of $1/(1-x)=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n$.

Comment: @KentaS Sorry, I don't understand how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of a power series $n x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647587/sum-of-a-power-series-n-xn)

Comment: @HansLundmark I believe it will! Thanks!

Comment: No one has mentioned that you seem to have taken the limit $N\to\infty$ wrongly. Note that in
$$Var(\bar{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{N}\left[ 1 + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\left( 1 - \frac{k}{N} \right) \alpha^k \right]$$
the quantity $N$ appears in **three** places. In two of them, you cannot just "replace" them with $\infty$, but at the same time no instance of $N$ can remain after taking $\lim_{N\to\infty}$.

Comment: the sum is similar to one that appears here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3194201/why-does-this-identity-hold-for-fejér-kernels/3414831#3414831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either take the derivative approach as Kenta S mentioned, or do the following:

$$S=\sum_{1}^{\infty} k\alpha^k  \\ \alpha S= \sum_1^{\infty} k\alpha^{k+1} = \sum_2^{\infty} (k-1)\alpha^k =\sum_{2}^{\infty} k\alpha^k -\sum_2^{\infty} \alpha^k \\ =(S-\alpha) -\frac{\alpha^2}{1-\alpha} \\ \implies S= \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} +\left ( \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} \right)^2$$

Comment: Thanks, what is the method of differentiating a series called? I believe I've forgotten this trick.

Comment: @s5s It’s probably just called ‘differentiating a series’. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: @s5s : Do you perhaps search the term "termwise differentation"?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\alpha^k$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=i}^{\infty} \alpha^k$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha^i \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha^k$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha^i \frac{1}{1-\alpha}$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-\alpha} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha^i $$
$$=\frac{\alpha}{(1-\alpha)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Comments for the save.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \alpha^k=\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\alpha^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \alpha^{k}-\alpha \sum_{k=0}^\infty\alpha^k$$

which is
$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\frac{\alpha^2}{1-\alpha}-\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}$$
$$=(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha})^2+\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}$$

Answer (score 0):

So I answer it this way. This answer assumes $|a| < 1$.

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k a^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k a^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a \frac{d}{d a} [a^k] = a \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{d}{da}[a^k] = a \frac{d}{da}[\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k] = a \frac{d}{da} [\frac{1}{1-a}] = \cdots
$$